# CruiseControl secure a build project node

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, cctray

Is there a way to secure a build project node in cruisecontrol? I would like to restrict the use of force build to specific users.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done by adding a `<security>` tag in the project config.

```
<project name="TestProject">
  <security type="defaultProjectSecurity" defaultRight="Deny">
    <permissions>      
      <rolePermission name="TestProjectAdmin" ref="FractionFactionAdmin" />
    </permissions>
  </security>
</project>

<internalSecurity>
  <cache type="inMemoryCache" duration="30" mode="sliding"/>
  <users>
     <passwordUser name="user1" password="change"/>
     <passwordUser name="user2" password="change"/>
  </users>
  <permissions>
    <rolePermission name="TestProjectAdmin" defaultRight="Allow" forceBuild="Allow" viewProject="Allow" startProject="Allow">
       <users>
         <userName name="user1"/>
         <userName name="user2"/>
       </users>
    </rolePermission>  
 </permissions>
</internalSecurity>
```

try like this